# How do you verify the purchase state of an SKProduct object?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, skproduct

What is the method for verifying the purchase state of an SKProduct object? Do you have to create a payment queue and inspect the transaction it returns? Is there not a better way?

I just want to silently check the purchase state. Is it better to just assume everything is locked if there's no stored purchase state? How do you know if the restore option should be  available?